# I have a syntax error in my R function code

Tags: r, function, bzip

I have a syntax error in my R function code, and I can't find it. Before I made it into a function it worked fine. I am new to R, and this is the first meaningful function I made (after making smaller test functions).

```
#model bzip
{
  #Likelihood:
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    Y1[i] ~ dpois(mu1[i])
    Y2[i] ~ dpois(mu2[i])
    mu1[i] <- (1-u[i, 1])(1-u[i, 3])
    (lambda0 + lambda1)
    mu2[i] <- (1-u[i, 1])(1-u[i, 2])
    (lambda0+lambda2)
    u[i, 1:4] ~ dmulti(p[], 1)
  }
  for(i in 1:3)
  {
    log(q[i]) <-alpha[i]
    p[i] <- q[i]*p[4]
  }
  p[4] <- 1/(q[1]+q[2]+q[3]+1)
  log(lambda0) <-beta[1]
  log(lambda1) <-beta[2]
  log(lambda2) <-beta[3]
  zdp <- p[1]+p[2]*(exp(-lambda0 -lambda1))
  +p[3]*(exp(-lambda0 -lambda2)) +
    p[4]*(exp(-lambda0 -lambda1 -lambda2))
  #P(Y1=Y2=0)
  zdp1 <- p[1]+p[3]+(p[2]+p[4])*(exp(-lambda0
                                     -lambda1)) #P(Y1=0)
  zdp2 <- p[1]+p[2]+(p[3]+p[4])*(exp(-lambda0
                                     -lambda2))#P(Y2=0)
  e1 <- (p[2] +p[4])*(lambda0 + lambda1) # E(Y1)
  e2 <- (p[3] +p[4])*(lambda0 + lambda2) # E(Y2)
  #Priors:
  for(j in 1:3)
  {
    beta[j]~ dnorm(0, 0.001)
    alpha[j]~dnorm(0, 0.001)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code quickly, is that the complete code you need to run?
There are a number of variables (e.g. int, vectors) that are **not defined**, for example take a look here:

```
  for(i in 1:n)
  {
    Y1[i] ~ dpois(mu1[i])
    Y2[i] ~ dpois(mu2[i])
    mu1[i] <- (1-u[i, 1])(1-u[i, 3])
    (lambda0 + lambda1)
    mu2[i] <- (1-u[i, 1])(1-u[i, 2])
    (lambda0+lambda2)
    u[i, 1:4] ~ dmulti(p[], 1)
  }
```

From where the variable **n** in the loop definition is coming from and what it is its supposed value (how many times the loop is supposed to run?)

Another one: from there the vector **u** is coming from?

I would check all the names and variables declaration first, or if I am wrong, can you please post all the code for us to run it?